# Multiple lvms or one large lvm

Tags: filesystems, lvm

Say you have a server that has two VGs (base and sys) and base is the standard partitions (root, var, etc.) and sys would be application specific partitions.

I can't find any real documentation for having stacked(?) partitions. That is to say:
/oracle as an lvm and then two other lvms mounted at /oracle/xxx and /oracle/yyy that will hold all application specific parts or if it makes more sense to make one large /oracle.

I have limited diskspace, and the one application tends to fill up full disk. I want to know which setup would be the more "correct" way to configure the system.

Is there a preferred way to this or is it really up to personal preferance?

Comment: in my case i use the the server internal disk space in vg00 and them i create root,var,opt and so on, my data disk coming from san, so i usualy create an other vg.

Answer (score 1):

**If you have limited space available, you should not over-fragment it in multiple LVs**. You can create a single large "data" LV and use it to store all user/application data.

If you need to mount that single LV in multiple directories, you have two options:

1. mount it under a single location (eg: /mnt/data) and use symlinks to point to it;
2. mount it under a single location (eg: /mnt/data) and use the bind mount option to remount part of it on another directory tree.

Option n.1 is simpler to manage ("low-maintenance" burden) and generally give good results, while option n.2 is somewhat more advanced but at the cost of higher difficulty to manage ("high-maintenance" burden).

Comment: So then, on a system with excess storage, would it make sense to have multiple LVMS (1 specific lvm for each application) or make a large data one???

Comment: On system with large storage capacity, a single large LVM is a bad idea, probably. But it really depends on the application you want to use. For example a dedicated virtualization host can be OK with a single large volume and file system. Anyway, remember that very large logical volumes can paint you in a corner if used with file systems that can not be shrunk. Thin logical volumes are a different beasts, and very large logic volumes can be used without too much fear. So, it really depends on the applications you plan to use. In some cases I used large LV, in others multiple smaller ones.